# Calculate the necessary sigma value for Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I want to construct a 1D Normal distribution (zero centered) using

- number *n*
- probability *p*

so that the resulting density distribution has probability *p* for *n* (and also *-n*) and smaller probability for larger numbers.

Can you please help me out with the calculation of the necessary sigma value?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking, for example, for $X\sim N(0,\,\sigma^2)$ so that $P(X\ge n)=P(X\le-n)=p$?

Comment: Exactly, thanks for rephrasing more clearly.

Comment: Hint: you want $n$ to be $\Phi^{-1}(1-p)$ standard deviations above the mean. where $\Phi^{-1}$ denotes the $N(0,\,1)$ distribution's [inverse CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function).

Comment: So we scale the sigma by a factor and get the final solution:
sigma = n / ppf(p, sigma=1)

Right?

Comment: Was that the answer? Can you please post a complete answer if you have figured it out since there are only hints here?